# How to get the select value attribute of ui:inputRadio

Tags: lightning-aura-components

im using:

```
<ui:inputRadio aura:id="rt" label="{!rt.Name}" value="{!rt.id}" text="{!rt.id}" change="{!c.selectedType}" name="rt" />
```

to display a list of recordtypes and i need to access the Id of the selected recordtype. However using the following:

```
selectedType:function(component, event, helper) {
        var rtName = event.getSource().get("v.label");
        console.log('@@@@@@@@@@@@ ' + event.getSource().get("v.label"));
        console.log('@@@@@@@@@@@@ ' + event.getSource().get("v.name"));
        console.log('@@@@@@@@@@@@ ' + event.getSource().get("v.value"));
        console.log('@@@@@@@@@@@@ ' + event.getSource().get("v.text"));
        //console.log("val1 = "+event.target.value);
        if(rtName!=''){
            component.set("v.SelectedRT",rtName);
        }
    },
```

i still cant access the Id, both

```
event.getSource().get("v.value");

event.getSource().get("v.text");
```

return true, not the Id of the Recordtype. Any ideas?

EDIT: with console output

11:06:18.142 Contact_NewBtn.js:44 @@@@@@@@@@@@ Candidate

11:06:18.142 Contact_NewBtn.js:45 @@@@@@@@@@@@ rt

11:06:18.142 Contact_NewBtn.js:46 @@@@@@@@@@@@ true

11:06:18.142 Contact_NewBtn.js:47 @@@@@@@@@@@@ true

Comment: can you provide actual console debug log, because according to [example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/ui:inputRadio/example)  it should work.

Comment: added console output